# appending output of nested for-loop to empty dictionary, only last output added to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I'm working on a problem where I would like to add every output of a for loop to an empty dictionary that was already created before the for-loop. But the problem is that I either get a value for only the last item in the dictionary or I get the same value for every row in the dictionary.

Here is an example of what I did :

```
#create 2 lists to loop through
list1= [10,20,30, 40, 50, 60]
list2= [1,2,3,4,5,6]

#create empty dict with list1 as the keys
n = { k: [] for k in list1 }

#create empty list and fill it in with loop
a=[]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        b= 10*j+i   
        print(b)
    a.append(b)
        
# fill in the dict
n[i]=a

print(n)
```

this gives the output:

```
{10: [], 20: [], 30: [], 40: [], 50: [], 60: [70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]}
```

and when I indent the n[i] this happens:

```
#create 2 lists to loop through
list1= [10,20,30,40,50,60]
list2= [1,2,3,4,5,6]

#create empty dict with list1 as the keys
n = { k: [] for k in list1 }

#create empty list and fill it in with loop
a=[]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        b= 500*j+i        
        a.append(b)
# fill in the dict
    n[i]=a


print(n)
```

with the output:

```
{10: [70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120], 20: [70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120], 30: [70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120], 40: [70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120], 50: [70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120], 60: [70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]}
```

where I would have wanted:

```
{10: [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], 20: [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80], 30: [40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], 40: [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100], 50: [60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110], 60: [70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]}
```

I hope somebody knows what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The 2nd code you provided gives completely different results than those in question.

Comment: Indenting `n[i]` is an obvious fix, but why `10` has been changed to `500` ?

Answer (score 0):

`a=[]` is outside the loop, so it always points to the same list. You need to initialise it inside the outer for loop, so on each iteration you get pointer to a new list that you can assign to each of the dictionary values.

```
#create 2 lists to loop through
list1= [10,20,30, 40, 50, 60]
list2= [1,2,3,4,5,6]

#create empty dict with list1 as the keys
n = { k: [] for k in list1 }

#create empty list and fill it in with loop
for i in list1:
    a=[]
    for j in list2:
        b= 10*j+i   
        a.append(b)
    n[i]=a

print(n)
```

You actually don't even need to define `a` list.
You can make an empty list as a value of a dict directly:

```
for i in list1:
    n[i] = []
    for j in list2:
        b= 10*j+i   
        n[i].append(b)
```